# MYSQL: UNION results between two tables where omitting records from first table if PK found in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two tables `products` and `product_edits` which hold product information on the pricelist. My app works in a way that if user changes any product info in `products` table it inserts it into `product_edits` table...

PRODUCTS table

```
pk|code|name     |description|price|....
-----------------------------------
1 |QW1X|Product 1|...
2 |LW1X|Product 2|...
3 |DE1X|Product 3|...
```

PRODUCT_EDITS table

```
pk|product_id|code|name              |description|price|....
-----------------------------------
1 |         2|LW1X|Product 2 new name|...
```

In above case I would like an SQL that returns records from both tables, but if product is found in `product_edits` table it selects only from `product_edits` and not also from `products` table.

I tried using standrd union but selects all records from both tables:

```
select code, name, description from products
union
select code, name, description from product_edits
```

Comment: Are you keeping multiple product edits in that table - i.e. if you update LW1X to "product 2 new-new name" will you then have two records in product_edits, or just the one? If the latter, I would ask what the point would be (why not just update products?), if the former, you will need to deal with your subselection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, in this case.
You want the search to stop once you found a match, not go over all of the results from `product_edits`.

So do it like this:

```
SELECT
    code, name, description
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_edits e WHERE e.code = p.code)
UNION
SELECT
    code, name, description
FROM product_edits
```

Comment: yes this is the preferred behaviour and optimised... though the solution provided by @scubasteve623 is also working

Answer (score 1):

```
select code, name, description from products
where code not in(select code from product_edits)
union
select code, name, description from product_edits
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use **IFNULL** function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

If your tables are related, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.code, IFNULL(pe.name, p.name), IFNULL(pe.description, p.description) 
from 
    products p 
    left join product_edit pe on (p.id = pe.product_id)
UNION
SELECT 
    pe2.code, pe2.name, pe2.description
from 
    product_edits pe2
```

The first part will give you the products that are only in products table and the products that are in both tables, but with product_edits.description.

The second part will give you the products that are only in products_edits table, because union will remove repeated records

Comment: This dos not work, still selects rows from both tables

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake. The colunm name that varies. So, IFNULL should be applied in that column, not description (or both columns if description and name are different).

Comment: The important here is the concept of to return the equal record in two parts of union. I'm sorry for the mistake.